# LuaRings - How to access values set in slave states (by stable.set) in master state?

Tags: lua

Minimal example is really the 2nd example from [Rings main page](http://keplerproject.github.com/rings/manual.html#examples)

```
require"rings"

local init_cmd = [[
require"stable"]]

local count_cmd = [[
count = stable.get"shared_counter" or 0
stable.set ("shared_counter", count + 1)
return count
]]

S = rings.new () -- new state
assert(S:dostring (init_cmd))
print (S:dostring (count_cmd)) -- true, 0
print (S:dostring (count_cmd)) -- true, 1
S:close ()

S = rings.new () -- another new state
assert (S:dostring (init_cmd))
print (S:dostring (count_cmd)) -- true, 2
S:close ()
```

However, I'm not able to get value of `shared_counter`. `print(shared_counter)` outputs `nil`.

I've tried to use `stable.get()`, but it says `stable` can only be used in slave states.
I finally tried

```
remotedostring("shared_counter = "..count)
```

Which worked, but I'm not quite sure if it's a proper way to do it. I guess direct access to `stable` value table would be sufficent?

EDIT: Oh, and I forgot to add, that the main part of the problem is communicating in the other way - from master to slave.

Comment: I'd be really glad if the downvoters commented about *why* on earth they are downvoting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stable` library stores the values in a global table in the master state called `_state_persistent_table_`. Though obviously this is meant to be hidden and private.

If you're uncomfortable with this, `stable` just uses `remotedostring()` internally, and it would not be hard to do something like that yourself.

For master->slave, `slave:dostring()` should suffice, using similar techniques.

Comment: I guess that I'll just wrap the calls to `remotedostring` and `slave:dostring` into some functions. Thanks a lot ;)